# Which library does EditLine wrapper means?

Tags: php

My php5 is installed on debian8.

```
php5 -i |grep Readline
Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper
find / -name 'EditLine wrapper'
find / -name 'EditLine*'
```

No output as results of the  last two commands.
Which library does `EditLine wrapper` means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's readline functionality [can be installed](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/readline.installation.php) via [GNU Readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), or via [libedit](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/), which is

> an autotool- and libtoolized port of the [NetBSD Editline library](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libedit/?sortby=date#dirlist) (libedit). This [Berkeley-style licensed](http://www.netbsd.org/Goals/redistribution.html) command line editor library provides generic line editing, history, and tokenization functions, similar to those found in [GNU Readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

EditLine is effectively an alternative (and differently licensed) implementation of Readline.